# What happened to the these characters in Mad Max Fury Road?

Tags: mad-max, mad-max-fury-road

In the first act of Mad Max Fury Road, the war rig is manned by The Ace (oldest guy there, kind of a captain), and a crew of warboys. The last time we see them is just before Furiosa enters the storm, and they just stand there, on top of the rig, looking at it. I think there were 3 or 4 of them. In an ideal position to take back the rig.

Also, Organic Mechanic, and Miss Giddy? Did they just disappear after Splendid's death?

What happened to them? Does Ace appear later on?

edit: Ace was knocked off the rig by Nux's ramming. What about the rest?

Comment: Doesn't Furiosa knock him off the War Rig? I know a lot of his crew at attacked and killed by the other gang at the start.

Comment: I honestly don't remember if he fell off. A lot of them died, yes, but at least 3 survived. And Ace. Even if he fell off, what about the others? They could just go up to the cabin and get in through the roof

Comment: @Petersaber I think it's sort of implied that they get blown away in the sandstorm... I think.

Comment: @Daft actually, I've got to expand the question a lil' bit. What happened to Organic Mechanic and the old lady with tattoos?

Comment: Either the extended edition on DVD / deleted scenes or sequels will answer these questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't remember where I read it, but apparently there's a deleted scene where Organic is taking a dump in the desert and Joe drives off without him chasing the war rig after they are heading back to the citadel.

As for Ace, I think you can see them blown off in the tornado that also got the pursuit vehicle that the war rig rammed.

Here's the "source"

http://www.kpopstarz.com/articles/207313/20150602/mad-max-fury-road-deleted-scenes-angus-simpson.htm

Comment: A source on the Organic scene would be nice. And yeah, appereantly Ace's crew is sucked in by the tornado